# Avoid matlab command history time stamp

Tags: matlab, shell, history

I have a shell script that calls matlab in a for loop.

```
for i in ${list}; do 
    nohup matlab -minimize -nodesktop -nosplash function_call(i, other_variables);
done
```

Now if I open matlab my command history will contain a short time stamp for each time I issued function_call in the for loop. For example after running the loop for 10 different i's, my matlab command history looks like this

```
%-- 08/19/2013 02:41:23 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 02:53:11 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:11:52 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:12:58 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:17:44 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:24:51 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:30:36 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:35:33 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 03:43:21 PM --%
%-- 08/19/2013 04:04:31 PM --%
```

This is not very useful and it clutters my command history. Is there a way to avoid command history from adding a line each time matlab is launched from my shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this script in your [`startup.m`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/startup.html) file to remove those lines when MATLAB starts:

```
H.file = fullfile(prefdir, 'history.m');
copyfile(H.file, [H.file '.bak'], 'f');
H.log = fileread(H.file);
H.handle = fopen(H.file, 'w');
H.stat = fwrite(H.handle, regexprep(H.log, '(%-- [^%]* --%(\n|\r)*)*', ''));
H.stat = fclose(H.handle);
clear H
```

The file that contains the history is located in preference folder [`prefdir`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/prefdir.html) and named [`history.m`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/command-history.html). The rest is a regular expression that matches those lines in the end of file. I put all variables in the script into a structure so that I can clear them all by `clear H`. `H.stat =` is used to avoid creation of `ans` variable.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have write permission to /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/toolbox/local/ which I believe is where startup.m would have to be located. I was hoping for an option I could pass from the shell script to prevent it from writing to history.m at all.

Comment: `startup.m` does not need to be located in `toolbox\local`. It can be located in your MATLAB startup folder (the folder you are in when MATLAB starts). Additionally, when you are starting MATLAB as you do from a shell script, you can specify the startup folder directly with the `-sd` option. Thus you could place the script from the answer in that folder and have it execute *only* when you run MATLAB from the shell script, but not interactively.